# Canary needed for packaged Chrome app development on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-app

I was trying to start with creating a Chrome packaged app using Linux as my development platform. The notes on http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab1_setup.html say I need a Canary build, which on Mint Linux/Ubuntu seems quite hard to install.

Is Canary really needed or can I just use another build like unstable or maybe even stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps development in general can be done on stable. New API may not be available, including small new portions of old apis. If you intend to ship an app now, it is best to test it on stable.

The code lab made use of APIs that were only recently introduced when it was written. If something doesn't work, trying a less stable build of chrome may get you the newer API support you need.

Beta or Dev channel is a reasonable choice for that, but if you modify your system browser you may suffer from bugs while on the bleeding edge.

Personally, I use [recent Chromium builds](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html), manually updating occasionally.